# How to retrieve mysql blob data which is image and store back on disk as a file in php

Tags: php, mysql, image, image-processing

I have an image stored as blob data in mysql ,I know how retrieve that from the database ,but I want to know how to create an image file back from that data and store it on disk?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: please check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745278/converting-blob-image-to-file-in-php